# Broken C code for reading database

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf, strcmp

I have a snippet of code, in C for reading entries from a passwd-style database:

```
do {
    if (fscanf(db, "%s:%s:%d", uname, passwd, &gid) == EOF) {
        return NULL;
    }
} while (strcmp(uname, username));
```

However, when running it, it gives a segmentation fault. After running it in the debugger, I found that the `strcmp` part is the part raising the segfault. Data types:

- `db` is `FILE *`, opened already.
- `uname` and `passwd` are `char *`, both initialised to NULL
- `username` is `char [64]`
- `gid` is `int`

How can I fix this problem, and alternatively how can I parse the database without needing to use this ugly hack?

Comment: no, would that be the problem? If so, I seriously need to improve my C...

Comment: @user3121023 using arrays worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both the string variables `uname` and `passwd` are just pointers, that doesn't point anywhere, what do you think happens when `fscanf` tries to use those pointers and write the string into memory?

That will lead to *undefined behavior*, as will the dereferencing done in the `strcmp` call.

You should use arrays for the `uname` and `passwd` variables as well.

Comment: Ah yes, this fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Then please award the answer, so that it's crystal cllear for others reading this question in future

Comment: @Mawg stackoverflow: "You can accept the answer in 10 minutes" so I'll wait a while.